# Using Johnny-five API with RFID Controller Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, rfid, adafruit, johnny-five

Is it possible to use the [Adafruit PN532 NFC/RFID Controller Shield](http://www.adafruit.com/products/789) with the [Johnny Five API](http://johnny-five.io)? I've searched the depths of google and I'm unable to find anything so far. If it is possible, how can I go about this?

I'm using an Arduino Uno with this.

Comment: Have you tried routing through the serial port as suggested in https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/804 ? I might try this as I'm trying to do the same thing.